# What is difference between different types of ads on google play services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

What is difference between Banner Ads 1, Banner Ads 2, Interstitial Ads, Smart Banners? How does their ecpm differ. Which ad type is best to show on my app? Which ad type can bring most revenue?

Answer (score 0):

The Banner types are provided so you can make a decision on which banner to show based upon the width in density independent pixels.

The best solution is to use Android resource config to specify the ad banner size. Example:

```
final AdSize adSize;
final int adBannerSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.adBannerSize);
switch (adBannerSize) {
    case 1 :
        adSize = AdSize.BANNER;
        break;
    case 2 :
        adSize = AdSize.IAB_BANNER;
        break;
    case 3 :
        adSize = AdSize.IAB_LEADERBOARD;
        break;
    default:
        Log.w(TAG, "No AdSize specified");
        adSize = AdSize.BANNER;
        break;
}
```

If you don't want to dynamically switch between ads, you can rely on SMART_BANNER to auto detect the width of the phone in its current orientation, and make the ad view that size". More Info [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/smart-banners).

However, there have been reports that SMART_BANNER is not the best for good CTR and we should dynamically switch between ad sizes for admob.

Unlike banners, interstitial ads provide a full page ad experience.

Interstitials due to their nature, brings most revenue when implemented well.

You should implement both interstitials and ads in a way that doesn't interrupt user experience to maximize revenue.

Comment: Can i implement both types of ads at once in my application. Also i tried to use smat_banner but the size of banners did not change it was constant.

Comment: Yes, you can implement both. However, it all depends on the type of app/game. How are you testing the size? It should change based on the device's/emulator's width in its current orientation. Also are you handling your own configuration changes?

Comment: I thought i don't need to worry about screen size when implementing smart banners.

Comment: I meant use devices or emulators of different screen sizes to ascertain if the smart_banner is indeed changing size automatically!